# How to develop stream server in .net

Tags: asp.net, audio-streaming, windows-media-server

We are developing a new, high volume, streaming music service; a personal Internet radio station, fully user programmable to play a unique personal non-stop stream of music. How to develop this kind of application in asp .net

Answer (score 0):

I am not the subject matter expert but http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/forpros/server/server.aspx can help you. See if windows media server can fulfill your requirements.