# How to do music streaming

Tags: asp.net, streaming

I want to develop a web application which gets media files from a streaming server and plays it on my website. How can I do this using ASP.NET?

Comment: It is duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426440/how-to-develop-stream-server-in-net/4427320#4427320.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your requirement? What kind of streaming? Will you provide free access to all your users? How many users? Will there be content protection or users will be free to download?

Answer (score 1):

[Windows Media Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496884/how-to-do-music-streaming) should be able to help you.

If it is just for hobby then make your music directory as `Virtual Directory` in your IIS and then enable permission for `Directory Browsing`. When user clicks on any song or playlist then `Windows Media Player/Default Player` of your machine should be able to play it automatically.

But if it is for some commercial reason then it would be better to look out for some sophisticated solution.